# How to get AudioComponent's Description Type letter code?

Tags: swift, audiounit

I'm trying to understand AudioComponents before instanciate them and understand/use AudioUnits...

I create an AudioComponentDescription by using wildcards:

```
var inDesc = AudioComponentDescription(componentType: OSType(),
                                    componentSubType: OSType(),
                               componentManufacturer: OSType(),
                                      componentFlags: UInt32(0),
                                  componentFlagsMask: UInt32(0))
```

I look how many AudioComponent there is:

```
AudioComponentCount(&inDesc) // returns 98 in a playground (ok)
```

I focus the first AudioComponent by using "nil" as first parameter in AudioComponentFindNext:

```
var currentComp = AudioComponentFindNext(nil, &inDesc)
```

Looking at its name:

```
func getAudioComponentName (componentInit:AudioComponent) -> CFString {
    var componentProp:AudioComponent = componentInit
    var componentNameProp:CFString = "" as CFString
    var unmanagedCurrentCompName:Unmanaged<CFString>?
    AudioComponentCopyName(componentProp, &unmanagedCurrentCompName)
    componentNameProp = unmanagedCurrentCompName!.takeRetainedValue()
    return componentNameProp
}
var currentComponentName:CFString = "" as CFString
currentComponentName = getAudioComponentName(currentComp) // returns "Apple PAC3 Transcoder" (ok)
```

At this point, the following tries will not be "ok".

I want to know much more about this "Apple PAC3 Transcoder" and its description:

```
// Creating an empty AudioComponentDescription
var currentComponentDescription = AudioComponentDescription()
// Gettings currentComp's description (type)
AudioComponentGetDescription(currentComp, &currentComponentDescription)
var compDescType:OSType = currentComponentDescription.componentType // returns 1633903715
```

At the last line of code, how could I get the letter code described in *AUComponent.h*:

```
enum
{
    kAudioUnitType_Output                   = 'auou',
    kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice              = 'aumu',
    kAudioUnitType_MusicEffect              = 'aumf',
    kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter          = 'aufc',
    kAudioUnitType_Effect                   = 'aufx',
    kAudioUnitType_Mixer                    = 'aumx',
    kAudioUnitType_Panner                   = 'aupn',
    kAudioUnitType_Generator                = 'augn',
    kAudioUnitType_OfflineEffect            = 'auol',
    kAudioUnitType_MIDIProcessor            = 'aumi'
};
```

for further compatibility I prefer to not have to reproduce this "enum" in my code.

Comment: At this moment i'm looking at kAudioUnitProperty_GetUIComponentList ...

Answer (score 0):

componentType is an `OSType` which is 4 ASCII character codes packed into 32 bits.

`1633903715` in hexadecimal is `0x61636463`

`0x61636463` in ascii is `'acdc'` (0x61 = 'a', 0x63 = 'c', etc...)